# How to drop the key value of a query in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop the key values`2041` and `3833` from their respective min and max searches. How do I do that?

```
cheapest = avocado[avocado['Price']==avocado['Price'].min()]
cheapest = cheapest.get('Region')
cheapest
```

[image]

```
2041    CincinnatiDayton
Name: Region, dtype: object

most_expensive = avocado[avocado['Price'] == avocado['Price'].max()]
most_expensive = most_expensive.get('Region')
most_expensive

3833    SanFrancisco
Name: Region, dtype: object
```

Comment: What do you mean by _key value_? It isn't clear to me what you're trying to do, and the accepted answer is vastly different from the two other ones, so I'm probably not the only one who's confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.values` to get the result as an array instead of indexes series:

```
cheapest.values
```

To reset the index, you can do:

```
cheapest = cheapest.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run the everything in two lines:

```
avocado.loc[avocado['Price']==avocado['Price'].min(), 'Region'].iloc[0]
avocado.loc[avocado['Price']==avocado['Price'].max(), 'Region'].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cheapest=avocado[avocado['Price']==avocado['Price'].nsmallest(2)].iloc[-1,:]

most_expensive=avocado[avocado['Price']==avocado['Price'].nlargest(2)].iloc[-1,:]
```